# JDBI gives error "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement" when using @UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbi

I'm trying to create a DAO interface that links up with a dao.sql.stg string template file. The query is very simple, just a select by id.

MyDao.groovy:

```
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
@RegisterMapperFactory(BeanMapperFactory.class)
interface MyDao {
  @SqlQuery
  Foo getFooById(@Bind("fooId") long fooId)
}
```

MyDao.sql.stg:

```
group MyDao;

getFooById() ::= <<
    SELECT bar, baz
    FROM foos
    WHERE fooid = (:fooId)
>>
```

My backend db is oracle. I've tried this query in Oracle SQL Developer and it works just fine but when I run the query using the app and the sql.stg file it gives me:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

I suspect that it's somehow not finding the sql.stg file to use even though I included the resources dir in the POM.

How can I get JDBI to find the correct sql.stg string template file? I've followed the example of other DAOs in this app and they use the exact same setup.

Edit: Note that if I hardcode the query string into the @SqlQuery annotation in the DAO interface instead of using the stringtemplate file then it works fine. So the problem is definitely that the dao can't find or process the stringtemplate file correctly. Here is the full stack trace:

```
ERROR [2015-04-15 11:22:29,588] com.yammer.dropwizard.jdbi.jersey.LoggingDBIExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: a5dfcceea8110fd1
! java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

! at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3685) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1376) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
! at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[tomcat-dbcp-7.0.37.jar:7.0.37]
! at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[tomcat-dbcp-7.0.37.jar:7.0.37]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.SQLStatement.internalExecute(SQLStatement.java:1300) ~[jdbi-2.41.jar:na]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.Query.fold(Query.java:172) ~[jdbi-2.41.jar:na]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.Query.first(Query.java:267) ~[jdbi-2.41.jar:na]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.Query.first(Query.java:259) ~[jdbi-2.41.jar:na]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.ResultReturnThing$SingleValueResultReturnThing.result(ResultReturnThing.java:91) ~[jdbi-2.41.jar:na]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.ResultReturnThing.map(ResultReturnThing.java:32) ~[jdbi-2.41.jar:na]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.QueryHandler.invoke(QueryHandler.java:45) ~[jdbi-2.41.jar:na]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject.invoke(SqlObject.java:147) ~[jdbi-2.41.jar:na]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject$1.intercept(SqlObject.java:60) ~[jdbi-2.41.jar:na]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.CloseInternalDoNotUseThisClass$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$19df5856.getFooById(<generated>) ~[jdbi-2.41.jar:na]
! at com.mydomain.mypackage.dao.MyDAO$getFooById.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
! at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) ~[groovy-all-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
! at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108) ~[groovy-all-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
! at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) ~[groovy-all-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
! at com.mydomain.mypackage.resources.FooResource.testDaoGetter(FooResource.groovy:374) ~[classes/:na]
! at com.mydomain.mypackage.resources.FooResource.this$3$testDaoGetter(FooResource.groovy) ~[classes/:na]
! at com.mydomain.mypackage.resources.FooResource$this$3$testDaoGetter$3.callCurrent(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
! at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49) ~[groovy-all-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
! at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133) ~[groovy-all-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
! at com.mydomain.mypackage.resources.FooResource.test(FooResource.groovy:352) ~[classes/:na]
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
! at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
! at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.yammer.metrics.jersey.InstrumentedResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TimedRequestDispatcher.dispatch(InstrumentedResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:32) ~[metrics-jersey-2.2.0.jar:na]
! at com.yammer.dropwizard.jersey.OptionalResourceMethodDispatchAdapter$OptionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(OptionalResourceMethodDispatchAdapter.java:37) ~[dropwizard-core-0.6.2.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceObjectRule.accept(ResourceObjectRule.java:100) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416) [jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538) [jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716) [jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669) [jetty-servlet-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448) [jetty-servlet-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at com.com.mydomain.mypackage.MyAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MyAuthenticationFilter.java:99) [auth-filter-1.0.0.1.jar:na]
! at com.mydomain.mypackage.MyHttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:32) [auth-filter-1.0.0.1.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at com.yammer.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29) [dropwizard-core-0.6.2.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455) [jetty-servlet-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384) [jetty-servlet-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at com.yammer.metrics.jetty.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:200) [metrics-jetty-2.2.0.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861) [jetty-http-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) [jetty-http-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:670) [jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) [jetty-util-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) [jetty-util-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
```

Comment: Can you try with   WHERE fooid = :fooId instead of  WHERE fooid = (:fooId)

Comment: No luck :( in fact it still doesn't work even if I hard code the fooId

Comment: Can you post full stack trace of the error ?

Comment: Not at the moment but I'll reproduce it tomorrow and then post

Comment: Just added the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. Ok, it turned out that it couldn't find the stringtemplate file because it was not in a directory that corresponded to that package of the DAO. I thought it was. My DAO was in the package:

```
com.mydomain.mypackage
```

meaning a directory of

```
src/main/java/com/mydomain/mypackage
```

However, the stringtemplate file was in the directory

```
src/main/resources/com.mydomain.mypackage
```

when it should have been in the directory

```
src/main/resources/com/mydomain/mypackage
```

They are displayed in the same way in Intellij.